# I'm having en error when I try to fetch the argument of an activeRecord object in a view in rails 2.3.11

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, view

Here is the error I get

```
ArgumentError in External_articles#show

Showing app/views/external_articles/show.html.erb where line #3 raised:

wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
Extracted source (around line #3):

1: <p>
2:   <b>Title:</b>
3:   <%= @external_article.title %>
4: </p>
5:
```

But in the console, It works fine.

```
?> ExternalArticle
=> ExternalArticle(id: integer, title: string, url: string, language: string, source: string, date: date, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, event_id: integer)

>> ExternalArticle.last.title
=> "Two course records shattered in Va. Beach marathon "
```

All the other attributes are displayed correctly in the view. And if I rename the title attritute to 'article_title' it will work.

I don't get what the problem is. The view used to work well.

Any clue?
Thanks

Comment: Can you post your external_articles_controller code?

Comment: So YOU say :)  The obvious things to check for are 1) is `@external_article` actually an instance of ExternalArticle and 2) is there a method called title, that takes one argument, in the ExternalArticle model or a class that ExternalArticle inherits from.

Comment: Thanks Tom, I couldn't find anything, so I renamed the attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the source of the problem. 
I had created a global helper method called title, that used a parameter.
When I renamed the helper method, everything worked again.